# How to handle when API Response returns either list or dict in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am parsing an API in python using `responseJson = json.loads(response.text)`

The API response is somewhat like this:

1. When having single entry in books

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "books": {
        "bookname": "BookA"
    }
}
```

or
2. When having multiple entries in books

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "books": [
        {
            "bookname": "BookA"
        },
        {
            "bookname": "BookB"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currenty I am using:

```
if type(responseJson['books']) is dict:
   bookName.append(responseJson['books']['bookname'])
    # do a lot more stuff
else:
    for val in responseJson['books']:
        bookName.append(val['bookname'])
            # do a lot more stuff
```

Since the code (# do a lot more stuff) is a bit complex, I was looking to find an optimized way to do this instead of relying on type().

Any suggestions on how to improve code quality here?

Comment: "type" or better "isinstance" is the usual way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `isinstance` instead of `type` but instead of having to different branches that do a bunch of stuff I would only look for the dictionaries and if found wrap place it inside of a list and then you only need one branch that does stuff.

for example:

```
books = response.json['books']
if isinstance(books, dict):
    books = [books]
for val in books:
    bookName.append(val['bookname'])
    #  do alot more stuff
```